# Eps file problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, eps

This morning I bought a file from fotolia. I tried to open the eps file with photoshop but got this error:

> "Could not open the file since PostScript instructions could not be analyzed".

What can I do?

Comment: Is this really the exact error you're getting? Doesn't seem so. I'd suggest to contact them and ask them if the file is corrupt. You bought something that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file in a text editor (eg. Notepad on Windows). PostScript files are text files and you should be able to read the contents. The first line should be something similar to:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
```

If it is, then your EPS file is probably corrupt.

If it is not, then your file is probaby another format **or** it may have been compressed prior to download, using a common format like ZIP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I opened the file with a text editor, as you suggested.
The first line is "%!PS-Adobe-3.0"; there's no "EPSF-3.0". should I add it? Sabrina

Comment: No, don't add it. That just means it is a PostScript file as opposed to an Encapsulated PostScript file. Because you can read it in a text editor, that means it is not compressessed. It may be corrupted ot truncated. You sould try to download it again and see if you have better results.

Comment: Maybe just rename the extension of .ps and try to open it in Photoshop again.